# How do I enable these arrows for soft-wrapped files

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to enable these arrows that are shown below for Typescript, Java and HTML. It seems that I have soft-wraps enabled, however nothing shows up when I pass the 120 margin.

[image: Softwraps Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure soft wraps in `Editor>General` in the `Soft Wraps` section:

[image: enable soft-wrap files]

Make sure to disable `Show soft wrap indicators for current line only`

And configure when to do a hard wrap in `Editor>Code Style`:

[image: configure hard wraps]

Comment: Okay, so I have those enabled. When I try the same lines as above, it just wraps with no arrows [link](https://imgur.com/YQ4lvKp)

Comment: There was a mistake in the first screen show. Make sure to disable `Show soft wrap indicator for current line only`.

Comment: Thanks for the context. I was able to finally get it to show when I set the color to be white in the code style configuration.